# Boost.Build and <link> feature for executables

Tags: boost, boost-build, bjam

What does it exactly mean, when I pass `<link>static` feature to requirements section when building an executable?

```
exe main
       : main.cpp
         /libs//my_library
       : <library>/boost//thread
         <link>static
       ;
```

Does this mean that both `/libs//my_library` and `<library>/boost//thread` **has** to be built with static linkage?

If my target `/libs//my_library` has `<link>static` requirement set (is built only with this feature), will there be raised an error if I ommit the `<link>static` requirement for all targets that depends on this library (just like the one above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it exactly mean, when I pass `<link>static` feature to
>   requirements section when building an executable?

It means to build (and link to) the dependency libraries statically.

> ```
> exe main
>        : main.cpp
>          /libs//my_library
>        : <library>/boost//thread
>          <link>static
>        ;
> ```
>
> Does this mean that both `/libs//my_library` and `<library>/boost//thread`
>   has to be built with static linkage?

Yes.

> If my target `/libs//my_library` has `<link>static` requirement set (is
>   built only with this feature), will there be raised an error if I
>   ommit the `<link>static` requirement for all targets that depends on
>   this library (just like the one above)?

No, that is OK. If your library has `<link>static` as a requirement, then it will be built statically no matter what, and it isn't necessary to have `<link>static` in a dependent target just for the sake of this library alone.

Note that it is possible to request a specific dependency library to be built statically without affecting other dependency libraries, like this:

`exe e : /libs//mylib/<link>static /libs//otherlib /libs//someotherlib`

This `<link>static` above doesn't affect `otherlib` and `someotherlib`, it pertains only to `mylib`.